# Custom, non-contiguous region polygons in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, polygon

Can anyone recommend a way of creating Google Maps polygons of custom regions comprising countries, say from lists of countries. Some of these regions will not be contiguous, although from the Maps docs it's seems like this is not a problem.

I see this site - http://www.gadm.org/country - has polygon data for all countries, although I can't think of a way to aggregate this data into regions.

**Update - solution now found, see my answer below**

I've made some progress, still not quite there. I downloaded the [Admin 0 – Countries](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/110m-cultural-vectors/) dataset from Natural Earth and loaded the shapefile in QGIS. Then I 'Toggle Editing', 'Open Attribute Table' and delete everything apart from USA and Canada.

I select these two rows and click 'Merge Selected Features', then save this as a KML file. If I load this into Google Maps as a KML Layer I see a polygon over North America. It seems to be empty though, if I attach a click handler it only works if I click on the polygon boundary.

There are also some odd little inland boundaries - I seem to be able to remove these using QGIS's node tool

If the above sounds sensible, does anyone know how I can complete this - make the polygons 'filled'?

Comment: http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_FusionTables_MultiCountryBrowser.html?countries=Afghanistan,Albania,Algeria,United%20States%20of%20America,Brazil

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't seen then - it looks interesting, I can't tell if it answers my question though?!

Comment: That is why it is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Ah ok - is it your site/page (I ask because of the correlation between your username and the domain name)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I have discovered enough to provide an answer, if it's helpful to anyone. I've done this:

1. Downloaded the [Admin 0 - Countries](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/110m-cultural-vectors/) dataset from the [Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/) site
2. Loaded ne_110m_admin_0_countries.shp in QGIS
3. In [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html) right-clicked this layer, and saved with a new name
4. On my new layer I right-clicked and selected 'Toggle Editing', right-clicked again and chose 'Open Attribute Table'
5. Selected countries to combine from the table and clicked the 'Merge Selected Features' button (and gave the new region a name)
6. Used the 'Node Tool' to remove any extraneous points in the new polygon(s)
7. Right-clicked the layer and clicked 'Toggle Editing' again, and saved the changes
8. Right-clicked one more time to choose 'Save as' and save to KML.

It seems I can use the resulting KML file in Google Maps, although I need to edit it first and set fill to '1', like this:

```
<Folder><name>my region</name>
  <Placemark>
    <name>Some name</name>
    <Style><LineStyle><color>ff0000ff</color></LineStyle><PolyStyle><fill>1</fill>
```

Hope this helps someone.